# How do you shuffle the contents of multiple files among themselves with minimal file access? (Bin shuffling)

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, file-io, shuffle

I have multiple files with sentences that I want to shuffle up. I want the files to remain the same but the sentences inside them should be shuffled across files.

Since they're files, it's important that file access is kept to a minimum otherwise it becomes too slow. This means that something like Fisher Yates will not be suitable since that would require accessing a file for every sentence.

Comment: Whats your environment?

Comment: @talles The files are Python pickles containing a list of sentences. The application is run on a low end desktop in Windows 7 with 4GB RAM. I was hoping for a generic abstract solution though.

Comment: what's called bin there? As you can't read/write pickled data in parts, i.e. you have to read/write the whole file each time, you can read all your files, determining strings counts, shuffle string indices in memory and reconstruct files. I doubt this approach can be optimized IO-wize

Comment: No, there are too many files to load at once into memory. It has to take place through partial transmission between files. The files are the bins and the data is being shuffled across bins.

Comment: It sounds like your asking how to read files without reading files.  You can either cut down on file i/o by reading large sections into memory or you can read in data in anyorder you want and and write it back out.  Not to mention that what alko has already mentioned, you can't half unpickle something so it's a moot point anyway.

Comment: @8bitwide I can fully read files. That's not the issue. What I want is an algorithm to shuffle data among files with the least amount of reading and writing. I can't read and write a file for every item in each file, that would be crazy. But that is how you would implement Fisher Yates in this scenario.